# Travis running in both com and org sites

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

Im trying to integrate travis with my Github project but kind of confused.

Not sure where I setup my account initially when I logged in - org or com.

Now, when I log through org or com, I see my build running for the project successfully.

https://travis-ci.com/PREM1980/udemy - Latest build failed
https://travis-ci.org/PREM1980/udemy - Latest build success

I get emails from .com saying my build failed but when I go to .org it ran successfully. Not sure how to fix this.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

On travis-ci.org, go to "settings" and you'll see "Legacy Integrations". Look up the offending repository and uncheck it using the "slider switch".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T32U.png)